# Помогите составить "дорожную карту" для Ruby for Web?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, планирование

После универа 2 года учил PHP и подрабатывал фрилансером. Вовремя одумался и сейчас нахожусь на распутье.
Решил выбрать Ruby, т.к., говоря словами Кеннеди: "Мы хотим полететь на Луну не потому, что это легко, а потому, что это сложно". То есть, хочу работать там, где нет толпы специалистов, спокойно и хорошо делать свою работу, программировать.

База в виде алгоритмического мышления, regexp со словарем, HTML, CSS имеется, поэтому очень надеюсь, что смогу быстро, за 4-6 месяцев, изучить Ruby и все, что нужно, и начать работать как фрилансер Ruby.

Вопрос у меня такой - пожалуйста помогите составить "дорожную карту" для Ruby for Web?
Что мне еще нужно знать помимо самого Ruby?

То есть, пожалуйста дополните или поменяйте местами пункты списка:

1. Ruby.
2. Фреймворк Rails.
3. HTML, CSS, Bootstrap.
4. ...
5. ...
6. ...
7. ...

Или Ruby on Rails мне хватит?
Я просто не имею хороших навыков, опыта, чтобы спланировать развитие самостоятельно, пожалуйста помогите начинающему коллеге пойти по правильному пути!

Comment: Добавьте как минимум базы данных и CRM. А так лучше смотреть на требования в вакансиях. Все расписано.

Comment: Попробовал Ruby, выбрал Python.

Answer (score 5):

Ruby on Rails, при кажущемся зашкаливающем количестве "волшебства" внутри это **текучая абстракция** ([leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html)) и в конечном счёте изучать фреймворк приходится "снизу": от средств, с которыми он облегчает работу. Он предназначен не для тех, кто "пока не умеет", скорее для тех, кто "умеет, но задолбался".

- **HTML и CSS** якобы уже есть. Хорошо, но я уточню, что нужно. Rails добавит ряд хаков на основе JavaScript, но достаточно хорошо зная способ общения браузера с сервером, их можно разобрать по документации. Если будете активно использовать общение с сервером через **формы** (а не через JavaScript), то стоит изучить, в каком виде передаются данные из них: скажем, почему у группы радиокнопок должен быть одинаковый `name`.
- Обмен данными идёт по **HTTP**. Знать идеи, на которых он основан, полезно, как и уметь смотреть, что делает браузер при открытии некоторой страницы. То есть, стоит научиться пользоваться инструментами разработчика в браузере.
- **Linux и/или OSX**: даже не пытайтесь работать с Ruby on Rails под Windows. Если вы слишком привыкли, то хотя бы поднимите *виртуальную машину* с Linux. Любой Ubuntu-подобный дистрибутив (Xubuntu, Linux Mint) не потребует много времени на освоение, зато сэкономит много часов и расширит набор доступных средств.

  - Придётся привыкнуть к работе с командной строкой в терминале: у Rails довольно много средств, которыми можно пользоваться только через неё.
  - Сервера, преимущественно, тоже ж на Linux. *Разрабатывать в среде, максимально приближенной к боевой* это хорошая идея. Это касается *не только ОС*, кстати. Есть известный пример в книге Майкла Хартла, где рекомендуют у себя запускать приложение с SQLite, а на хостинге с PostgreSQL. Если не отклоняться от книги, это будет работать. Но если делать что-то своё, различия быстро дадут о себе знать.
- Можно сразу изучать **Rails**, *если готовы **не** броситься его применять на практике*, потому что **Ruby всё равно потребуется**, как только пойдут задачи посложнее "Hello, world!" и генерируемых каркасов.

  - Поэтому начать с **Ruby** — хорошая идея.
- **Реляционные базы данных**: "из коробки" в Rails есть средства общения только с ними. Другие средства постоянного хранения придётся прикручивать самостоятельно, что для новичка не самое простое занятие. Чтобы начать работать с Rails, хватит понимания концепций "таблицы", "базы данных" и "столбца".

  - **SQL** будет *необязателен **поначалу***. Встроенный в Rails интерфейс (язык запросов ActiveRecord) неплохо покрывает простые запросы, а в режиме разработки показывается SQL, который выполняется в результате. Поэтому основы SQL можно изучить уже "по ходу", но по мере усложнения запросов придётся закопаться в сам SQL (в отрыве от Rails) поглубже.
  - Попадаются призывы писать "портируемые запросы", которые не используют особенностей отдельных диалектов SQL и работают на всём (или почти всём), что поддерживает ActiveRecord. Прежде чем прислушиваться к ним, уясните для себя, что это просто *лишь поначалу*, а в большинстве случаев это просто не нужно, т. к. есть возможность запустить на той базе, для которой приложение разработано. На это можно убить очень много времени, после чего понять, что это того не стоило.
- Учитесь работать с чужим кодом. "Гуляйте по экосистеме", ищите библиотеки. Сообщество очень богато на код для решения часто встречающихся (не всех, но многих) задач. Пробуйте их на практике. Учитесь работать с документацией. Если найдёте задачу, для которой приемлемого решения на данный момент нет, попробуйте собрать и опубликовать собственное. Возможно, кто-то скажет вам "спасибо".

Это всё, что касается самих веб-приложений на Rails. Остались нетронутыми области касательно самого процесса разработки (редактор с отловом ошибок [всякие linter'ы], стайлгайд и Rubocop, контроль версий [в основном Git], автотестирование [общая теория и RSpec]) и разворачивания на сервер (что больше про системное администрирование).

К сожалению, текстовый формат не позволяет адекватным образом нарисовать "карту", по которой можно ориентироваться. [Проблема востребованности таких материалов известна](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2790/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8B).

Answer (score 1):

Дополню список:

- Git
- Реляционные СУБД(Postgres, MySQL)
- Хранилища данных - Memcached, Redis
- Развертывание приложений(RVM, настройка продакшн-сервера, деплой приложения)
- Очереди задач(Sidekiq)
- Websocket
- Сейчас модно делать SPA(Single Page Application), используя Rails-приложение в качестве API, а значит нужно владеть клиентскими MVC-фреймворками, например Backbone или Angular